# How to get Numeric value of Z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, z-index

I am trying to get the z-index property of some div using the following code.

```
$("#elementID").css("z-index")
```

But i am getting

`"auto"` as result.

is it possible to get the Numeric values like 1,2,3..  in this case instead of auto .

please share the link, if this question has already answered in Stackoverflow.

Comment: Try this: https://api.jqueryui.com/zIndex/

Comment: which z-index you have set in your css for element?

Comment: did you set an actual numeric value for the z index?

Answer (score 6):

**jQuery UI:**

To get the numeric value of the z-index property of your div regardless if it was set directly on it or inherited use:

```
$("elementID").zIndex();
```

*Notice:* **`zIndex`** was removed in jQuery UI 1.10.

This method will start at the specified element and move on to its parents until it finds an element that has a z-index set. If it doesn't find anything, it will return 0.

**JavaScript:**

```
window.getZIndex = function (e) {      
    var z = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(e).getPropertyValue('z-index');
    if (isNaN(z)) return getZIndex(e.parentNode);
    else return z; 
};
```

Use it like so:

```
var z_Index = getZIndex($('#elementID')[0]);
```

Comment: I am getting zIndex is a not function error , Do i  missing anything

Comment: It shows you this error, because you haven't linked the jQuery UI. .zIndex() is a jQuery UI method. Check edit for more.

Comment: also zIndex() has been removed from jQueryUI

Comment: Thanks, I clarified it in the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

It's a known bug in *-webkit-browsers* like Chrome, IE, etc. where one cannot get the `z-index` value. Although one can set and see the effect.

I tried in Firefox and was able to get the value.
You need to find an alternative.

Read about the bug [**here**](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9667).